# Activemq concurrency fail in Apache camel route

Tags: concurrency, apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic, apache-servicemix

Trying to send multiple requests at same instant to camel activemq route, one request is serviced and the other request is not serviced and sent back as it is. The Jms messages are set with JMScorrelationId too before sending like below

```
textMessage.setJMSCorrelationID(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
```

below is my activemq route

```
from("activemq:queue:TEST_QUEUE?disableReplyTo=true")
                .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut)
                .process(new Processor() {
                    public void process(Exchange e) throws Exception {
                        log.info("Request : "
                                + MessageHelper.extractBodyAsString(e.getIn()));
                        /*Processing Logic*/
                    }
                })
                .beanRef("testBean","postDetails")
                .inOnly("activemq:queue:TEST_QUEUE");
```

Multiple (Test for 2 requests) requests sent to the above route concurrently not serviced except one. The servicemix.log shows all recieved requests. But only one is serviced.

Below is the code what is sending request deployed in jboss 6.1 as part of web application.

```
public Message receive(String message, String queueName) {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
                "tcp://localhost:61616");
        String userName = "smx";
        String password = "smx";
        Connection connection;
        Message response =null;
        try {
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(userName, password);
            connection.start();
            ((ActiveMQConnectionFactory) connectionFactory)
                    .setDispatchAsync(false);
            Session session = connection.createSession(false,
                    Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            Queue destination = session.createQueue(queueName);
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
            producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
            TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage(message);
            Queue tempQueue = session.createQueue(queueName);
            textMessage.setJMSReplyTo(tempQueue);
            producer.send(textMessage);
            MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(tempQueue);
            response = consumer.receive();
            response.acknowledge();

            session.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Is there some or the other parameter im missing?? please suggest.

Comment: Exactly how are you sending requests concurrently? You are picking up messages from a queue. There is only one message at the front of the queue at any given instant.

Comment: There is a application deployed in one system. This web application is accessed using ip address by 2 different systems. These two systems send requests at a time.

Comment: Yes, but there is still only one message at a time getting to queue TEST_QUEUE where the route picks up the message. Also, keep things simple when you are starting. Test it with one system first and make sure both work. Then switch to second and make sure that works. Then test with both. If everything is exactly the same then there is no reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: Since its a web application, Request can be made from browser. From multiple tabs, requests cant be made at a time hence request is made from 2 different machines but from same application. Also As per your sayings, sequence of requests from same machine works fine.

Comment: use createTempQueue to create a real temporary queue. You end up creating a regular queue that you share in concurrent requests, and hence get mixed data. Otherwise you need to build logic in the receive method to use JMS selectors to pick the message with the JMSCorrelationID you want

Comment: See for example: http://activemq.apache.org/how-should-i-implement-request-response-with-jms.html

Comment: Modified my code referring to above example it looked fine. Request is sent from client. Server processed the request, sent the response. But on client side the onMessage() is not getting called. Sometime it throws exception like "there is already a consumer available". Even i modified my activemq route like u have mentioned below.

Answer (score 1):

Camel will auto send back a reply if the JMS message has a JMSReplyTo header, so your route should just be

```
from("activemq:queue:TEST_QUEUE")
                .process(new Processor() {
                    public void process(Exchange e) throws Exception {
                        log.info("Request : "
                                + MessageHelper.extractBodyAsString(e.getIn()));
                        /*Processing Logic*/
                    }
                })
                .beanRef("testBean","postDetails");
```

At the end of the route (eg after calling testBean) then the content of the message body is used as the reply message, that are sent back to the queue named defined in the JMSReplyTo header.

Comment: Yes thanks for suggestion it works. But my actual concurrency problem is still not working. I made sure JMSReplyTo header and JMSCorrelationID set in the header. I can see the concurrent requests logged. But Response interchange and response lost cases happens... Anything im missing...

Comment: Well you are not telling us what is sending and handling the receive of those messages. So if there is interleaved data from there, its very likely a problem in that code/library or what you use.