# Apache Camel Netty Socket

Tags: tcp, apache-camel, netty

I want to use apache camel netty connection in client mode. And also this client is not in syncrionized mode. I provided following configuration to achive this but appache created two connection to server one for receving message and one for replying to it. how we can use netty connector in this mode.

```
from("netty4:tcp://localhost:7000?sync=false&allowDefaultCodec=false&encoder=#stringEncoder&decoder=#stringDecoder&clientMode=true&reconnect=true&reconnectInterval=1000")
            .process(new Processor() {
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    exchange.getOut().setBody("Hello " + exchange.getIn().getBody());
                }
            })
            .to("netty4:tcp://localhost:7000?sync=false&allowDefaultCodec=false&encoder=#stringEncoder&decoder=#stringDecoder&clientMode=true");
```

and in Hercules Utitly i see two connection for this request processing

```
11:00:51 AM:  127.0.0.1 Client connected
11:00:51 AM:  127.0.0.1 Client connected
```

Comment: Well you are accepting a connection on port 7000 and sending to the same host on port 7000..why?

Comment: as i have to use same port for request and reply for a transaction.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a bit confusion. What exactly is it you are trying to achieve? From the looks of it, you are receiving on port 7000 and then post to port 7000 again which means your "from" will get triggered and post to your "to" which sends to your "from" again. Is this really what you want?

Comment: Let me explain in detail. I need a client which is connected to a server. But the server can send message me on that connected socket as well. Then i am processing the message and replying back on same socket.

Comment: Ok but that is not what you are doing there. You are telling the server to call itself.

Comment: I don't think you need the "to" endpoint for request-reply to work, see the request-reply examples on the Camel Netty4 page: http://camel.apache.org/netty4.html

Comment: i have used from and to clientMode=true. it works well as it responds back to server after processing but only issue is that i want to use same connection for responding back and also work in async mode.

Comment: after receiving request from server. i want to push that in a MQ and wait on other MQ for processed response. so when packet is processed and available in MQ i want to use same connection to transmit response to socket.

Answer (score 2):

So this is what you want right?
"after receiving request from server. i want to push that in a MQ and wait on other MQ for processed response. so when packet is processed and available in MQ i want to use same connection to transmit response to socket".

So first thing is to probably agree on some requirements. If you need to send a response back i.e. a client is waiting to hear back regarding the request it sent, then it should be synchronous communication and not asynchronous.

So you can then simply write:

```
from("netty4:tcp://localhost:7000?sync=true&allowDefaultCodec=false&encoder=#stringEncoder&decoder=#stringDecoder&clientMode=true&reconnect=true&reconnectInterval=1000")
            .process(new Processor() {
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    exchange.getOut().setBody("Hello " + exchange.getIn().getBody());
                }
            })
            .to("ACTIVE_MQ");
```

Off course in the active mq part you need to set the reply to and time out so that if you don't get a response in time it times out and you notify the client with some good error message.

What will happen is that the message is received, and sent to an active mq queue with the appropiate reply to properties. If the message is received, the response is sent back over the same connection to the client.

I would advise you to read upon on the JMS request/reply in Camel as it will help you to setup the active mq part.
http://camel.apache.org/jms.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply i will test this thing in morning.

Comment: You can also look at Claus Ibsens answer and code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33887676/activemq-concurrency-fail-in-apache-camel-route